# Robot Framework - How to start with pabot.PabotLib Library?

Tags: python, robotframework

Pabot document provides an example to illustrate how to call it, just like:

```
***Settings***
Library    pabot.PabotLib

*** Test Case ***
Testing PabotLib
    Acquire Lock   MyLock
    Log   This part is critical section
    Release Lock   MyLock

    ${valuesetname}=    Acquire Value Set
    ${host}=            Get Value From Set   host
    ${username}=        Get Value From Set   username
    ${password}=        Get Value From Set   password
    Log   Do something with the values (for example access host with username and password)

    Release Value Set
    Log   After value set release others can obtain the variable values
```

But, I just can "Library pabot", it always remind "Unknown 'pabot.PabotLib' library" when I try to "Library pabot.PabotLib" in my RED RobotEditor and Pycharm.

How should I call the "pabot.PabotLib" in my IDE?

Comment: Did you already install pabot into your machine ?

Comment: Environment:python 3.7, robot framework 3.0

Comment: yes, I sure, and I can "from pabot import PabotLib" in my python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pabot and RED approach Robot Framework in different ways. RED's approach is functional and will run scripts/suites one at a time which allows for complex features like debugging. The approach of Pabot is to run suites in parallel. RED is unable to handle the data stream in parallel and as such it should not be expected that you can run this with the same features as a the regular robot approach.

This is why loading the `pabot.PabotLib` in RED will also not work. However, there is a way to get the library keywords recognized. This won't make running Pabot from  RED possible but will at least help with the writing of the scripts.

When loading the below XML as a libspec file in the RED.xml in the Referenced Libraries section. This will ensure that the keywords and library is recognized.

**pabot.PabotLib.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<keywordspec name="pabot.PabotLib" type="library"
    format="ROBOT" generated="20181102 15:20:05">
    <version>0.28</version>
    <scope>global</scope>
    <namedargs>yes</namedargs>
    <doc>Documentation for test library ``pabot.PabotLib``.</doc>
    <kw name="Acquire Lock">
        <arguments>
            <arg>name</arg>
        </arguments>
        <doc>Wait for a lock with name.
            This will prevent other processes from acquiring the lock with
            the name while it is held. Thus they will wait in the position
            where they are acquiring the lock until the process that has it
            releases it.
        </doc>
        <tags>
        </tags>
    </kw>
    <kw name="Acquire Value Set">
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
        <doc>Reserve a set of values for this execution.
            No other process can reserve the same set of values while the set is
            reserved. Acquired value set needs to be released after use to allow
            other processes to access it.
        </doc>
        <tags>
        </tags>
    </kw>
    <kw name="Get Parallel Value For Key">
        <arguments>
            <arg>key</arg>
        </arguments>
        <doc>Get the value for a key. If there is no value for the key then
            empty
            string is returned.
        </doc>
        <tags>
        </tags>
    </kw>
    <kw name="Get Value From Set">
        <arguments>
            <arg>key</arg>
        </arguments>
        <doc>Get a value from previously reserved value set.</doc>
        <tags>
        </tags>
    </kw>
    <kw name="Release Lock">
        <arguments>
            <arg>name</arg>
        </arguments>
        <doc>Release a lock with name.
            This will enable others to acquire the lock.
        </doc>
        <tags>
        </tags>
    </kw>
    <kw name="Release Locks">
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
        <doc>Release all locks called by instance.</doc>
        <tags>
        </tags>
    </kw>
    <kw name="Release Value Set">
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
        <doc>Release a reserved value set so that other executions can use it
            also.</doc>
        <tags>
        </tags>
    </kw>
    <kw name="Run Only Once">
        <arguments>
            <arg>keyword</arg>
        </arguments>
        <doc>This is an *experimental* keyword for building setups that
            should be executed only once. As the keyword will be called
            only in one process and the return value could basically be anything.
            The "Run Only Once" can't return the actual value.
            If the keyword fails, "Run Only Once" fails.
            Others executing "Run Only Once" wait before going through this
            keyword before the actual command has been executed.
            NOTE! This is a potential "Shoot yourself in to knee" keyword
            Especially note that all the namespace changes are only visible
            in the process that actually executed the keyword.
            Also note that this might lead to odd situations if used inside
            of other keywords.
            Also at this point the keyword will be identified to be same
            if it has the same name.
        </doc>
        <tags>
        </tags>
    </kw>
    <kw name="Set Parallel Value For Key">
        <arguments>
            <arg>key</arg>
            <arg>value</arg>
        </arguments>
        <doc>Set a globally available key and value that can be accessed
            from all the pabot processes.
        </doc>
        <tags>
        </tags>
    </kw>
</keywordspec>
```

Comment: thanks so much, it works!!! why are you so excellent??
Are you a superman to save my planet?